# Where is the username and password used in Azure AD B2C (OpenID Connect)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I'm trying to understand where the username and password are used in Azure ad b2c, which uses openid connect.

At this point I'm thinking the username and password used in the B2c login page go against the active directory and only after the login is successful the openid flow starts.

Thus resulting in OpenID Connect not handling with user passwords at all unless you explicitly use ROPC flow.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely correct in your understanding. In Azure AD B2C (Business to Consumer), the handling of usernames and passwords is primarily managed by the identity provider (IdP), which in this case is Azure AD B2C. if you want i can breakdown the flow fir you,

Users enter credentials on the Azure AD B2C login page.
Azure AD B2C authenticates the credentials against its identity store.

Upon successful authentication, Azure AD B2C generates security tokens, including an ID token.

OpenID Connect flow begins, exchanging tokens between client, Azure AD B2C, and user's browser.

The client application uses the ID token to obtain user information securely.

Comment: Hi there mate, thanks for the swift response and help me understand this. where have you read this info I was trying to find official docs and couldn't find it. the best I could find was this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/media/custom-policy-overview/user-journey-diagram.png from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview

Comment: Hi mate thanks for letting me know, this is pretty much the knowledge I have about the auth flows. and been here once with similar question, pretty much of the info will be available over documentations and Microsoft qanda platform too.

Comment: Thanks for the transparency mate, I'll mark the answer until the end of the day. and by the way, happy new year!!!

Comment: you are more than welcome, happy new year have a great year ahead.

Comment: Mohamed just to conclude I read the specification and found it written that the way the authorization server authenticates the end-user is beyond the scope of openid specification. this reinforces yours answer of being the idP who decides. "The methods used by the Authorization Server to Authenticate the End-User (e.g., username and password, session cookies, etc.) are beyond the scope of this specification." from here https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html . case closed! cheers